how to check irreducibility over a finite field?
Here I am struck at a question:
Let F be a field of 64 elements. If $p(x)=x^8-1$ and $q(x)=x^7+1$ then
(A) $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have roots in F.
(B) $p(x)$ has root in F and $q(x)$ has no root in F.
(C) $q(x)$ has  a root in F and $p(x)$ has no roots in F
(D)neither $p(x)$ nor $q(x)$ has a root in F.
Actually I have dealed with problems to check whether the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{R,C,Q}$ type problems. And being a polynomial of such higher will be always reducible over $\mathbb{R,C,Q}$. This is something new.. Here I am given a field with 64 elements and asked to check the irreducible or not. How to deal with this sum...please let me know....
Thanks in advance!!

The question seems to ask about the polynomials having a root, not about them being reducible. These are not equivalent - the first implies the second, but not the other way. Why are you asking specifically about (ir)reducibility? PS The question is very simple the way it stands now: $1$ is a root of both polynomials (recall that $-1 = 1$ in fields of size $2^n$).

What theorems do you have at your disposal? Do you know, for example, that every degree $6$ irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}2$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}{2^6}$? Or that a polynomial irreducible over $ \mathbb{F}2$ of degree $k$ remains irreducible over $\mathbb{F}{2^m}$ if $\gcd(m,k)=1$?
